# Error enumerating unfinished transactions: Error Domain=ASDErrorDomain Code=509 "No active account" UserInfo={NSLocalizedDescription=No active account

Tags: android, ios, flutter, in-app-purchase, revenuecat

hi i'm developing an flutter app about daily horoscope and tarot cards and i'm planning to sell subscription on that and for that i'm using revenuecat i done all the settings in appstore connect and revenuecat but when i'm trying to get purchases and package offerings there's nothing happening its just a blank button and then i saw this errror in the logs "[Default] Error enumerating unfinished transactions for first transaction listener: Error Domain=ASDErrorDomain Code=509 "No active account" UserInfo={NSLocalizedDescription=No active account}"

i looked up in here and apple forums but all the solutions arent working for me i'm using my iphone device and created a sandbox test user i really dont know what to do from that and i could really use some good advices or experienced persons solutions